# Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'split' was called on null

Tags: firebase, flutter

This is a simple contact app that allows to add view and edit contact details of individuals. The error here can't be totally understood by me.

```
 class ViewContact extends StatefulWidget {
  final String id;
  ViewContact(this.id);
  @override
  _ViewContactState createState() => _ViewContactState(this.id);
}

class _ViewContactState extends State<ViewContact> {  
  DatabaseReference _databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
   String mascot = "https://learncodeonline.in/mascot.png";
   String id; 
  _ViewContactState(id);
  Contact _contact;                                   
  bool isLoading = true;

  getContact(id) async {
     _databaseReference.child(id).onValue.listen ((event){
      setState(()  {
        print(event.snapshot);
        _contact =   Contact.fromSnapshot(event.snapshot);
        isLoading = false;
        print(_contact.lastName);
      });
    });
  }
  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    this.getContact(id);
  }

  callAction(String number) async{
    String url = 'tel: $number';
    if (await canLaunch(url)){
      await launch(url);
    }
    else {
      throw 'Could call $number';
    }
  }
  smsAction(String number) async{
    String url ='sms: $number';
    if (await canLaunch(url)){
      await launch(url);
    }
    else {
      throw 'lol';
    }
  }
  navigateToLastScreen(){
    Navigator.pop(context);
  }
  navigateToEditScreen(id){
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context){
      return EditContact();
    }));
  }
```

The error shown is below. Can the error be because of the id variable? (Pretty new towards Flutter).

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'split' was called on null.
E/flutter (12369): Receiver: null
E/flutter (12369): Tried calling: split("/")
E/flutter (12369): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:50:5)
E/flutter (12369): #1      DatabaseReference.child (package:firebase_database/src/database_reference.dart:24:58)
E/flutter (12369): #2      _ViewContactState.getContact (package:firebase_authentication/screens/view_contact.dart:24:25)
E/flutter (12369): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (12369): #3      _ViewContactState.initState (package:firebase_authentication/screens/view_contact.dart:36:10)
E/flutter (12369): #4      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4033:58)
E/flutter (12369): #5      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3902:5)
E/flutter (12369): #6      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3084:14)
E/flutter (12369): #7      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2887:12)
E/flutter (12369): #8      SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5092:14)
E/flutter (12369): #9      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3084:14)
E/flutter (12369): #10     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2887:12)
E/flutter (12369): #11     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
E/flutter (12369): #12     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
E/flutter (12369): #13     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3907:5)
E/flutter (12369): #14     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3902:5)
E/flutter (12369): #15     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3084:14)
E/flutter (12369): #16     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2887:12)
E/flutter (12369): #17     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5092:14)
E/flutter (12369): #18     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3084:14)
E/flutter (12369): #19     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2887:12)
E/flutter (12369): #20     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5092:14)
E/flutter (12369): #21     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3084:14)
E/flutter (12369): #22     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2887:12)
E/flutter (12369): #23     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5092:14)
E/flutter (12369): #24     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3084:14)
E/flutter (12369): #25     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2887:12)
E/flutter (12369): #26     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5092:14)
E/flutter (12369): #27     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3084:14)
E/flutter (12369): #28     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2887:12)
E/flutter (12369): #29     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
E/flutter (12369): #30     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
E/flutter (12369): #31     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3907:5)
E/flutter (12369): #32     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4053:11)
E/flutter (12369): #33     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3902:5)
E/flutter (12369): #34     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3084:14)
E/flutter (12369): #35     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2887:12)
E/flutter (12369): #36     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
E/flutter (12369): #37     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
E/flutter (12369): #38     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3907:5)
E/flutter (12369): #39     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3902:5)
E/flutter (12369): #40     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3084:14)
E/flutter (12369): #41     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2887:12)
E/flutter (12369): #42     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
E/flutter (12369): #43     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
E/flutter (12369): #44     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart
```

this is the stack over flow error i am facing. Well same as the previous error , i can't figure out this one too :(

```
I/flutter ( 4594): The following StackOverflowError was thrown building ViewContact(dirty, state:
I/flutter ( 4594): _ViewContactState#4e21c):
I/flutter ( 4594): Stack Overflow
I/flutter ( 4594):
I/flutter ( 4594): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter ( 4594): #0      Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:4)
I/flutter ( 4594): #1      Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #2      Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #3      Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #4      Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #5      Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #6      Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #7      Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #8      Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #9      Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #10     Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #11     Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #12     Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #13     Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #14     Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #15     Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #16     Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #17     Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #18     Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #19     Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #20     Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #21     Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #22     Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #23     Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #24     Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #25     Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #26     Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #27     Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #28     Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #29     Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #30     Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #31     Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #32     Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #33     Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #34     Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #35     Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #36     Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #37     Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #38     Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #39     Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #40     Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #41     Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #42     Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #43     Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): ...
I/flutter ( 4594): ...
I/flutter ( 4594): #59478  Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #59479  Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #59480  Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #59481  Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #59482  Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #59483  Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #59484  Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #59485  Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #59486  Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #59487  Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #59488  Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #59489  Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #59490  Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #59491  Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #59492  Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #59493  Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #59494  Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #59495  Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #59496  Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #59497  Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #59498  Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #59499  Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #59500  Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #59501  Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #59502  Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #59503  Contact.email (package:firebase_authentication/model/contact.dart:25:29)
I/flutter ( 4594): #59504  _ViewContactState.build (package:firebase_authentication/screens/view_contact.dart:179:40)
I/flutter ( 4594): #59505  StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4012:27)
I/flutter ( 4594): #59506  ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3924:15)
I/flutter ( 4594): #59507  Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
I/flutter ( 4594): #59508  BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2340:33)
I/flutter ( 4594): #59509  _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding&WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:700:20)
I/flutter ( 4594): #59510  _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:285:5)
I/flutter ( 4594): #59511  _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1016:15)
I/flutter ( 4594): #59512  _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:958:9)
I/flutter ( 4594): #59513  _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:874:5)
I/flutter ( 4594): #59517  _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:236:10)
I/flutter ( 4594): #59518  _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:194:3)
I/flutter ( 4594): (elided 3 frames from package dart:async)
```

================================================================================
This is the Widget Associated with the View Contact state.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Add Contact"),
        centerTitle: true,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
          onPressed: (){navigateToLastScreen(context);},
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: (){
                  this.pickImage();
                },
                child: Center(
                  child: Container(
                    width: 130.0,
                    height: 130.0,

                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 4.0),
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,

                      image: DecorationImage(
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                        image: _photoUrl=="empty"? NetworkImage("https://i.imgur.com/BoN9kdC.png"): NetworkImage(_photoUrl),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40.0),
              child: TextField(

                onChanged: (value){
                  setState(() {
                   _firstName = value; 
                  });
                },
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'First Name',
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
              child: TextField(

                onChanged: (value){
                  setState(() {
                   _lastName = value; 
                  });
                },
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Last Name',
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
              child: TextField(
                onChanged: (value){
                  setState(() {
                   _email = value; 
                  });
                },
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'E-mail',
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
              child: TextField(

                onChanged: (value){
                  setState(() {
                   _phone = value; 
                  });
                },
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Phone',
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
              child: TextField(

                onChanged: (value){
                  setState(() {
                   _address = value; 
                  });
                },
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Address',

                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            //save the shit
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
              child: RaisedButton(
                color: Colors.teal,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(50, 10, 50, 10),
                onPressed: (){
                  saveContact(context);
                },
                child: Text("ADD CONTACT", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure ID isn't null? Or Your database reference isn't null?

Comment: I am sure the id isn't null, the error was due to the reason mentioned by kind people below :) Thank you for your concern

Answer (score 3):

I believe the **id is null**.

```
E/flutter (12369): #2      _ViewContactState.getContact (package:firebase_authentication/screens/view_contact.dart:24:25)
```

Following the stacktrace, this line raises the exception:

```
_databaseReference.child(id).onValue.listen((event)
```

```dart
E/flutter (12369): #1      DatabaseReference.child (package:firebase_database/src/database_reference.dart:24:58)
```

from database_reference.dart line 19-25:

```
  /// Gets a DatabaseReference for the location at the specified relative
  /// path. The relative path can either be a simple child key (e.g. ‘fred’) or
  /// a deeper slash-separated path (e.g. ‘fred/name/first’).
  DatabaseReference child(String path) {
    return DatabaseReference._(_database,
        (List<String>.from(_pathComponents)..addAll(path.split('/'))));
  }
```

path is your id, so I would say the id is null.

```
E/flutter (12369): Receiver: null
E/flutter (12369): Tried calling: split("/")
```

You can add assertion to the constructor, if id is null, an error will be thrown and you can then follow the stacktrace to find the broken code.

```dart
class ViewContact extends StatefulWidget {
  final String id;

  const ViewContact({Key key, @required this.id})
      : assert(id != null),
        super(key: key);

  @override
  _ViewContactState createState() => _ViewContactState(this.id);
}
```

EDIT:

#1
change this line:

```dart
  _ViewContactState(id);
```

to

```
_ViewContactState(this.id);
```

**the field id in the state will never be updated!**

#2
you can access the id filed from the Widget class by calling **widget.id**
id will never be changed don't put it to the State constructor.

This should work

```dart
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ViewContact extends StatefulWidget {
  final String id;

  const ViewContact({Key key, @required this.id})
      : assert(id != null),
        super(key: key);

  @override
  _ViewContactState createState() => _ViewContactState();
}

class _ViewContactState extends State<ViewContact> {
  final DatabaseReference _databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
  final String mascot = "https://learncodeonline.in/mascot.png";

  Contact _contact;
  bool isLoading = true;

  getContact(id) async {
    _databaseReference.child(id).onValue.listen((event) {
      setState(() {
        print(event.snapshot);
        _contact = Contact.fromSnapshot(event.snapshot);
        isLoading = false;
        print(_contact.lastName);
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.getContact(widget.id);
  }

  callAction(String number) async {
    String url = 'tel: $number';
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could call $number';
    }
  }

  smsAction(String number) async {
    String url = 'sms: $number';
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'lol';
    }
  }

  navigateToLastScreen() {
    Navigator.pop(context);
  }

  navigateToEditScreen(id) {
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
      return EditContact();
    }));
  }
}
```

Comment: well, this did remove the error but stack overflow exception occurred. :(

 Another exception was thrown: Stack Overflow

Comment: I don't see any code line in the ViewContact widget that could throw the StackOverflowException. Please share the StackTrace, maybe it will be useful.

Comment: the stack trace doesn't show up. Only thing that is shown is 
I/flutter (16740): Another exception was thrown: Stack Overflow

Comment: Could you please share the whole ViewContact Widget class and the output from the IDE with exception text. Without additional information it is not possible to figure it out.

Comment: I have done it sir. Thank you for sticking with me here ! :)

Comment: I did find the reason. And it is because in the setter method in contact.dart file, i accidentally miss spelled a certain variable.
Thank you for your time Alexander !

Answer (score 2):

You should use

```
 _ViewContactState(this.id);
```

in the constructor, to initialise id. Otherwise it will be null, and hence the error.

However you don't really need to pass it, as the StatefulWidget can access it through the **widget.** call

```
class ViewContact extends StatefulWidget {
  final String id;
  ViewContact(this.id);
  @override
  _ViewContactState createState() => _ViewContactState();
}

class _ViewContactState extends State<ViewContact> {
  DatabaseReference _databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
  String mascot = "https://learncodeonline.in/mascot.png";

  _ViewContactState();
  Contact _contact;
  bool isLoading = true;

  getContact(id) async {
    _databaseReference.child(id).onValue.listen ((event){
      setState(()  {
        print(event.snapshot);
        _contact =   Contact.fromSnapshot(event.snapshot);
        isLoading = false;
        print(_contact.lastName);
      });
    });
  }
  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    this.getContact(widget.id);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Glen. Even this method removed the error but i am getting stack overflow exception now

 Another exception was thrown: Stack Overflow

Comment: A stackoverflow is another error completely. It is usually trigger by some code calling itself. Add some print statements in your code to see if you can spot it.